# How to find eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue=0 in the matrix mentioned

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

One  of the eigenvalues for this matrix is $0.$

Now I have to find eigenvector corresponding to $0.$ Using $A-\lambda I=0$
and reducing into reduced echelon form. I found the matrix as

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now basic variables(variables corresponding to leading 1's) are $x$ and $y.$ so $x=0, y=0.$ $z$ is not available. so how to find value of $z$ to find the whole eigen vector. Anyone solve this. I am stuck at $z.$

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think $\ z\ $ is "not available"?  Your reduced echelon form gives you the equations
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}\  ,
$$
from which you get $\ x=y=0\ $, just as you say.  But you can choose any value for $\ z\ $ that you please, and the equations will be satisfied.  To get an eigenvector, you simply need to choose any non-zero value for $\ z\ $.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my confusion @lonza leggiera. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if we have a nonzero eigenvector $\vec{x}$ for a matrix $A,$ any scalar multiple of $\vec{x}$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ with the same eigenvalue. For any real $c$:

$$A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} \Rightarrow A(c\vec{x}) = c(A\vec{x}) = c(\lambda\vec{x}) = \lambda(c\vec{x})$$

Because of this, the system you use to find the eigenvectors associated with a specific eigenvalue (the $(A - \lambda I)\vec{x} = 0$ system) will *always* be underdefined if there are nontrivial eigenvectors, and the eigenvectors are the *set* of solutions to that system.

So, here the eigenvectors are all vectors $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ z\end{bmatrix},$ which we can also write as $\vec{x} = z\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$